# Does ServiceStack Cache Internal Requests?

Tags: caching, servicestack

If I use the .ToOptimizedResult (documented [here](https://docs.servicestack.net/caching)) from a "bare" request like so:

```
var svc = new MyService();
var svcResul = svc.Any(new requestDTO() {..});
```

Will the performance of svcResult benefit from caching, or must it be called from Http/Messaging/Client ?

Note: app is actually running a servicestack container..  but caller above is not invoked from inside a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack doesn't do any Request Caching by default, you have to opt-in to Caching using one of the caching strategies.

You shouldn't use `ToOptimizedResult()` in Services that you wish to call directly, for cached Requests it returns a serialized compressed `byte[]` result which isn't accessible as a Typed Response DTO from C# API.

For caching Services that you want to call via C# you can use the [CacheResponse Attribute](http://docs.servicestack.net/cacheresponse-attribute) instead.

#### Calling Other Services

Note: The recommended way to call other Services is to use the [Service Gateway](http://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway), e.g:

```
var result = Gateway.Send(new RequestDto());
```

If you want to call the C# method on the Service directly you should use `ResolveService` to resolve an autowired Service and call the method within a using statement, e.g:

```
using (var service = base.ResolveService<MyService>())
{
    var result = service.Any(new RequestDto());
}
```

Comment: thanks so much.  One additional question, here http://docs.servicestack.net/cacheresponse-attribute it says the non-base url is the cache key -  does this apply non non-http callers (does it serialize the request dto for the key, effectively?)

Comment: @kevinc Caching and compression is only added for HTTP requests, I.e. for MQ or internal Service requests it’s executed without caching.